# What layout is better for a UI with two card cells per row?

Tags: ios, user-interface, design-guidelines

What is an optimal way to create a grid view for iOS with two columns per row as shown in the screenshot?

[image: grid]

I am currently using tableview with static cells, but the UI gets distorted on some iPad. Also how best to arrange the grid border? Currently I use imageview of center ones, and a new cell for the horizontal ones with an imageview. But this does not feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be made with an `UICollectionView`, it has a specific delegate which is `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` that makes it very easy to reach that appearance.

---

**Step 1**

Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your `UIViewController`, like: `<#Your View Controller#> : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

**Step 2**

The amount of cells per row is calculated based on the amount of cells that fit the UICollectionView width. Therefore, having cells with half the width will fit 2 cells per row.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 2, height: /* your desired height here */)
}
```

---

**Tips:**

You can even make it a little smaller than half the screen, by multiplying values like this: `(collectionView.frame.width / 2) * 0.98`, you can also subtract constant values.

You may need to set `collectionView.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0` since this attribute default value is `10.0`

---

**Documentation:** [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout)

Comment: How to add the border lines when using `UICollectionView`?

Comment: @jsloop that should be another detailed question, since there can be many approaches and many expected results.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for a UICollectionView!  (It shouldn't be too hard to change your UITableViewDataSource protocol methods to their UICollectionViewDataSource equivalents.)